# CSS Over-ride with Wordpress Plugin

Tags: css, wordpress

Can I have hand please? I am struggling to over-ride the CSS on the Wordpress Custom Fields Search plugin, which seems to use the same style for search boxes that appear in the widget and the page. If you look at http://www.landedhouses.co.uk/parties/, the white text is visible by the search boxes in the widget but not so visible on the page. Any ideas how to fix this!? Unfortunately adding this to the page's php didn't achieve anything:

```
    <h2>By size and price</h2>
<p style="color:000;"><?php if(function_exists('wp_custom_fields_search')) 
wp_custom_fields_search(); ?></p>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the style rule that is causing you problems.

```
/* searchforms.css line 15 */
.searchform-label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 4px;
  color: white;
}
```

You can do a few things using css.  You can make an overwriting rule in the style sheet:

```
.searchform-label {
  color: black;
}
```

if that doesn't work, you can make a more specific rule:

```
label.searchform-label {
  color: black;
}
```

or you can in the worst case scenario make an `!important` rule.

```
.searchform-label {
  color: black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an extension of the above answer (i still cannot comment :( )

Generally speaking, a more specific rule will override the property if the original is not using !important,

so as the original targets .searchform-label, you just need to target something more specific, such as label.searchform-label, and if that doesnt work, include a direct parent element and a `>` e.g. if the label is wrapped in a P, use `p>label.searchform-label`

there should rarely be a need for !important, although they should make a !notimportant, for easy override :D

Comment: Oooh - this has just worked: label.searchform-label {color: black;} However WHY does it work? Surely both the widget and page use label class=searchform-label? Thanks

Comment: Because label.searchform-label is more specific than than just .searchform-label the values are able to override any none-important rules, just as {parent}>label.searchform-label will override rules from label.searchform-label, i.e. for more specific a selector, the more likely the rule will be used

Hope this helps :)